# What is the correct way to decode "&Lowbar;" into "_"?

Tags: php, html-entities

I have tried using html_entity_decode but it didn't work.

What is the correct function to use it to decode it?

Comment: It should be an underscore "_"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply use `ENT_HTML5` flag with [html_entity_decode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php) :

```
echo html_entity_decode ('&lowbar;', ENT_HTML5);
```

Which print:

```
_
```

See PHP Manual:https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.html-entity-decode.php